# Calculating the area under the graph of a function.

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, area

I know this question might be very trivial for many of you, but I would appreciate if you take a look, in the following question I'm asked to calculate the area that is under the function's graph in interval $[0,3]$. I tried to use the idea of cutting the shape into rectangles and triangles and try to evaluate in what range the area could be, and this is what they are asking for.

here is the graph:

[image: this is the graph:]

and here is what I did:

[image]

I said that the area is surely bigger than the area I selected in picture A, which turns out to be 12. and did same principal to find the maximum area but calculating rectangles and in some cases removing areas of triangles to be more accurate, and what I got is 15.

so my final answer is that $12<area<15$ and for some reason its wrong.

can someone tell me why?

Comment: What is $\color{red} {10}$?

Comment: My eyesight is not good enough. But I can see $1$ for the height of the red area.

Comment: @zoli sorry, my mistake, corrected.

Comment: @zoli its not 10, it just indicates the height, which is 1.0

Comment: But the idea you sketched is correct. So just pay more attention to the book keeping of the pieces.

Comment: @zoli its a built in exercising program on my uni website. I tried many answers .. None of them is right.

Comment: Although the top of graph B is cut off, it looks like the area should be 16, not 15.

Comment: Surely you could say that area is between $-\infty$ and $\infty$. If the precision is what they are asking for, then you need to (or THEY need to) provide us what this precision should be: e.g. length of the interval is $0.5$ etc..

Comment: Are you really asked to estimate the area under the green graph? Not the area between the green and the red graph?
Why do you know that your answer is not correct. Is this a multiple choice question and your answer doesn't fit any of the given choices? If so, please give us the answers.

Comment: @sranthrop no its not multiple choice, u just enter the answer and check if its right. and to be honest, its not clear at all if they are talking about area between green and red, but I tried both, also didn't work.

Comment: Ok, but your idea is totally fine. With red you get $12<a<15$, and without red you get $9<a<12$.

Comment: If it is an online HW system, they sometimes don't want intervals (like $12<a<15$), but they actually want you to put in a number.  If you enter 13.5 (the average) for example, it may work.  Not that the answer is 13.5, but when the system checks, it'll check to see if the answer you enter is within the tolerance set by the instructor.  At least this has been the case when I've assigned online homework (for questions like this there is often a tolerance that the instructor can set).  It may not help in your case--if it is actually looking for an interval.

Comment: yeah, I know, its really weird.

Comment: @TravisJ yeah its talking about an interval.

Comment: @FirasAliAbdelGhani, in that case, I see no error with your logic or calculation.  Did they draw the rectangles for you? or was that your own doing?  There are so many ambiguities here, it is exactly why I don't like assigning (graded) homework like this--unless it is being done by hand.

Comment: @TravisJ I drew it. and ur right its confusing.

Comment: Since I am almost blind, I have problem looking precisely the graphs but your idea seems perfectly fine to me. I have been given the coordinates of the points and used a quite sophisticated method (Closed Newton-Cotes formulae based on $7$ points. For the area between the curve and the axis, I got $\frac{486}{35}\approx 13.89 $ so $\frac{381}{35}\approx 10.89$ for the other one. This totally agrres with sranthrop's comment.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I appreciate ur effort. but apparently its not the answer they want, maybe its more superficial than we think, I will keep waiting for other scenarios that people can think about.

Comment: Using a trapezoidal-like method I got $13.5<a<14.0$ with red and therefore $10.5<a<11.0$ without red.

Comment: @sranthrop. It seems that we perfectly agree ! Cheers :-)

Comment: @sranthrop I had this answer before. but tried it again to be sure. its not what they want. (im not saying the way is not correct) but they might have calculated it in a weird way so they got "specific" answer. and maybe they are wrong, I will consult someone at uni, but it will be until next week, I was curious to know the answer now.